# docpad: yaml postfix in metadata header

Tags: docpad

I have seen somewhere that `yaml` is added to the metadata section:

```
--- yaml
layout: 'post'
---
```

Why is that?

Comment: it's for blog posts read http://blog.omgmog.net/post/adding-more-post-metadata-to-jekyll-with-yaml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it myself.

The metadata section can be parsed either by `yaml` or `cson`. So a metadata section starting with `--- yaml`, or just `---`will be parsed with `yaml`, while a section starting with `--- cson` will be parsed as `cson`.

Comment: Yep. In the future we may move parsing over to plugins as well, so meta data can be parsed by anything!